# Updating Entry in Table - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like the one below, which I used a double for loop to calculate. The problem is, I'm getting different results for rows `test1 vs test2` and `test2 vs test1` (see intersection value, rate, and percentage columns in table). They should be the same. For example, `test1 vs test2` has an intersection value of 8910, a rate of 0.861618799, and a percentage of 86.1618799. How would I update the `test2 vs test1` row to contain these values as well?

| Peak Comparison | Param -a | Param -b | Intersection.Value | Total -a | Total -b | Rate | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 vs test1 | test1 | test1 | 9543 | 9543 | 9543 | 1 | 100 |
| test2 vs test2 | test2 | test2 | 9708 | 9708 | 9708 | 1 | 100 |
| test1 vs test2 | test1 | test2 | 8910 | 9708 | 9543 | 0.861618799 | 86.1618799 |
| test2 vs test1 | test2 | test1 | 8713 | 9543 | 9708 | 0.826817233 | 82.68172329 |

Comment: So why your results are not the same if your operations should be commutative?

Comment: Good question. It's the way a program called BEDtools calculates the intersection values seen in my table. It has to do with genomic overlaps, and unfortunately I haven't found a way to make the program give the same result with a double for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sort key from `Param -a` and `Param -b` to match the same records and group them. You can copy the first value of the group using `transform`:

```py
cols = ['Intersection.Value', 'Rate', 'Percentage']
key = df[['Param -a', 'Param -b']].apply(lambda p: tuple(sorted(p)), axis='columns')
df[cols] = df.groupby(key)[cols].transform('first')
```

```
>>> df
  Peak Comparison Param -a Param -b  Intersection.Value  Total -a  Total -b      Rate  Percentage
0  test1 vs test1    test1    test1                9543      9543      9543  1.000000   100.00000
1  test2 vs test2    test2    test2                9708      9708      9708  1.000000   100.00000
2  test1 vs test2    test1    test2                8910      9708      9543  0.861619    86.16188
3  test2 vs test1    test2    test1                8910      9543      9708  0.861619    86.16188
```